# How to plot points from a CSV file into a country polygon in Arcmap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, csv, point

I am trying to import points, which contain longitude and latitude data, to a geographic area (polygon) in ArcMap but they are not overlapping. I have added a point layer (.csv) to my table of contents and then a polygon that represents the geographic area of Sri Lanka.

When trying to export the points as an excel file it says that ' Failed to connect to the database. An underlying database error occurred. Class not registered'.

I have tried doing it the other way around, by first adding the country of Sri Lanka into the table of contents, first with and then without the .prj., then I inserted the points which contain latitude and longitude. After displaying XY data, the new layer does not contain the attribute information and again does not allow me to export it into a new layer. It says 'There was an error exporting the layer'. (The layer has no OID field. If this is the problem how can I add one?)
When checking the coordinate system under data frame properties, both, points and polygon seem to have the same coordinate (Kandawaal_sri_Langa_Grid).

Comment: Is your dataframe in the same coordinates than the points ? Can you provide a exemple of coordinate from the points and from the polygon ?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The Sri Lanka Map is originally in SL_grid_99
Authority: Custom

Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting: 200000.0
False_Northing: 200000.0
Central_Meridian: 80.77171
Scale_Factor: 0.9999238418
Latitude_Of_Origin: 7.00048
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0) .   The points don't have a coordinate system, just the latitude and longitude data. So I import them on the fly.

Comment: After I add the points to the dataframe, I disply the XY data and indicate the X and Y fileds. And that is when it says that my table does not have object ID field and that I should try to export as data. When I try to do this it says that there was an errror exporting the layer.